# Python Regular Expressions: Only if the word has a space and comma in front or if the word is a start word

Tags: python, python-re

For a given string like this:

```
'Rob and Amber Mariano, Heather Robinson, Jane and John Smith, Kiwan and Nichols Brady John, Jimmy Nichols, Melanie Carbone, Jim Green and Nancy Brown, Todd and Sana Clegg with Tatiana Perkin'
```

I want to identify couples or other family members who may be referred to as **"John and Jane Doe"** and *******exclude* cases like "Jim Green and Nancy Brown"****.**

I would like the following only to be identified:

```
Rob and Amber Mariano, Jane and John Smith, Kiwan and Nicholas Brady John, Todd and Sana Clegg
```

The groups from the regular expression below seems to catch most of the cases I want but I have having trouble excluding "Jim Green".

I would like to put the condition that the first word is a name but it is either at the start of the string or preceding it are only empty space and a comma.

But for some reason my expression is not working. I expected ([^|,\s']?) to capture that but it doesnt seem to be doing that.

```
([^|\,\s]?)([A-Z][a-zA-Z]+)(\s*and\s*)([A-Z][a-zA-Z]+)(\s[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+)(\s[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+)?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this... works perfectly as expected

```
(,\s|^)([A-Z][a-z]+\sand\s[A-Z][a-z]+(\s[A-Z][a-z]+)+)
```

Test script:

```
import re
a=re.findall("(,\s|^)([A-Z][a-z]+\sand\s[A-Z][a-z]+(\s[A-Z][a-z]+)+)","Rob and Amber Mariano, Heather Robinson, Jane and John Smith, Kiwan and Nichols Brady John, Jimmy Nichols, Melanie Carbone, Jim Green and Nancy Brown, Todd and Sana Clegg with Tatiana Perkin")
print(a)
```

Response:

```
[('', 'Rob and Amber Mariano', ' Mariano'), (', ', 'Jane and John Smith', ' Smith'), (', ', 'Kiwan and Nichols Brady John', ' John'), (', ', 'Todd and Sana Clegg', ' Clegg')]
```

Comment: I tried your solution on https://regex101.com/ and its working on "Jim Green and Nancy Brown" but is not catching "Rob and Amber Mariano"

Comment: its working. I had to remove the quotations from the test string. Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks! So my mistake was putting "\," instead of "," in the first group. if you look at the first group of the expression I was using. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Let's breakdown the answer into 2 simple steps.

1. Convert the entire string into a group of couple names.
2. Get all couples matching the requested pattern.

We are interested in couple names which follow the followign pattern :

```
<Name1> and <Name2> <Last-name> <May-or-may-not-be-words-separated-by-spaces>.
```

But we are only interested in the `<Name1> and <Name2> <Last-name>` part from each matched string. Now that we have defined what we want to do, here's the code for the same.

```py
import re

testStr = """Rob and Amber Mariano, Heather Robinson, 
Jane and John Smith, Kiwan and Nichols Brady John, 
Jimmy Nichols, Melanie Carbone, Jim Green and Nancy Brown, 
Todd and Sana Clegg with Tatiana Perkin
"""

# Pattern definition for the match
regExpr = re.compile("^(\w+\sand\s\w+\s\w+)(\s\w)*")

# Remove whitespaces introduced at the beginning due to splitting
coupleList = [s.strip() for s in testStr.split(',')]

# Find all strings that have a matching string, for rest match() returns None
matchedList = [regExpr.match(s) for s in coupleList]

# Select first group which extracts the necessary pattern from every matched string
result = [s.group(1) for s in matchedList if s is not None ]
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not addressing the issue of *excluding*  "Jim Green and Nancy Brown"

Comment: Not sure what you are doing but I don't see it in my output. Can you check once again? My code does *exclude* it.

Comment: your output has "Green and Nancy Brown". I don't want that to be selected.

Comment: @AmitSingh You are printing `Green and Nancy Brown` which should have been excluded

Comment: @Amatya can you verify now?

Comment: @AmitSingh The earlier issue is gone. thanks. Only one issue remaining. In the end of the test string we have "Todd and Sana Clegg with Tatiana Perkin" . We don't want the entire phrase selected but only "Todd and Sana Clegg"

Answer (score 2):

A bit late but probably the simplest regex

```
import re

regex = r"(?:, |^)(\w+\sand\s\w+\s\w+)"

test_str = "Rob and Amber Mariano, Heather Robinson, Jane and John Smith, Kiwan and Nichols Brady, John, Jimmy Nichols, Melanie Carbone, Jim Green and Nancy Brown, Todd and Sana Clegg with Tatiana Perkin"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        print (match.group(groupNum))
```

**Output:**

```
Rob and Amber Mariano
Jane and John Smith
Kiwan and Nichols Brady
Todd and Sana Clegg
```